# Using CSS Sprites in jQuery Plugin, Spritely?

Tags: jquery, css-sprites

I've always been terrible with CSS sprites.

I'm attempting to just mess around with the [jQuery plugin Spritely](http://www.spritely.net/) but I've been having some trouble just getting a sprite animation to successfully appear.

Here is my barebones HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Mario</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.spritely-0.4.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="mario"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my styling:

```
body {
    background: gray;
}

#wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

#mario {
    background: transparent url(images/sprites/sheets/mario_walk_right.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And finally, the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mario').sprite({fps: 8, no_of_frames: 5});
});
```

Now, I've made sure all of my file paths are correct, so that isn't the problem.  But, I'm just faced with a blank page, and no animation.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work with  style

```
#mario {
        background: transparent url('http://www.spritely.net/images/hills-for-docs.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
```

This also seems to work (downloaded from above url)

```
#mario {
    background: transparent url('hills-for-docs.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
```

Comment: Interesting.  I tried, and yes, it does work.  It doesn't really make sense considering the path is correct.  Also, I forgot quotes around the path url originally, but I tried including them, and still to no avail.

Comment: @BOSS you must have some problem with image, i checked into firebug and it is working (it changes background position of image).

Comment: OK, let me check with a different image.  I'd post my image but I don't have access to an FTP server at the moment.

Comment: Well, it turned out that by just shifting my CSS into the head of my page and into a `<style>` tag, for some reason it fixed my problem..  I don't understand why that should have an effect on anything, but it fixed the problem.